# Heroku raising 500 instead of 404 with Django app

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-urls

I have designed my app's `URLS` to match all the criteria and find it works perfectly on my local machine with `DEBUG=FALSE` however when deployed to [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) I seem to have a problem where all urls that should raise a **404** ends up raising a **500** ?

Has anyone encountered this before?

my URL pattern

```
url(r'^$', 'index', name='dashboard_index'),
```

when retrieving `http://localhost:5000/123/` it raises a 404 page

when retrieving `http://myapp.com/123/` it raises a 500 page

Comment: Have you checked the logs what is actually raising the 500 error?

Comment: Running right for me. Check other url patterns. See logs.

Comment: Are you sure it is runnning on the default port of 80?

Answer (score 4):

When you set `DEBUG` to `False`, you need to provide a `404.html` and a `500.html` somewhere that is in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. If you don't provide these, it raises a `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception, which is caught as a `500` error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those files are optional in newer Django versions.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, 90% of the time, 500 on 404 is caused by missing 404.html template. You're saying that you have it working locally, but I would still check if that template made to heroku, and if can cause any kind of error.